# OllyDBG, managed to patch file, now can I automate this?

Tags: ollydbg

In Olly I managed to patch the file to no longer compare for a specific flag. Is it possible to automate this?

Basically I changed a JNZ to a JZ.

Is there a way to could do the same thing with a hex editor?

The end goal would be to create a program to automate this patch.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean with 'automate'? you mean something like a plugin for Olly? or a standalone program that patches another program?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but if you replaced `jnz` by `jz` you *did not* patch anything to no longer compare any flag. You merely inverted the condition. Patching it to `jmp` would have been the proper way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I suppose you just want to create a program that patches the already existing file, so here's how I'd do it.

---

First, you need the offset in the file.
That means that offset 0 is the first byte, 1 is the second, etc, as opposed to the offset + base which you see in memory.

To get that offset, right click the instruction, and go to `View > Executable file`:

[image: executable file (to get the offset)]

And you take the offset:

[image: relative offset]

which is `0x16A7` in my case.

---

Once you have the offset, you must code a program to patch the program.
Here's a few ways: (I only tested the Python one, but the rest should work)

## C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream f("file_to_patch.exe", std::ios::binary);
    // seek to the desired offset
    f.seekp(0x16A7);
    // \x74 to \xEB, for example (conditional short to unconditional short)
    const char bytes[] = "\xEB";
    f.write(bytes, sizeof(bytes));
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

## C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* f = fopen("to_patch.exe", "r+b"); // open
    fseek(f, 0, 0x16A7); // seek to the offset to patch
    fwrite((void*) "\xEB", 1, 1, f);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

## Python

In case you want to script it and don't wanna bother with C / C++, here's how you do it with Python:

```
f = open("to_patch", "r+b") # open in read/write binary
f.seek(0x16A7) # seek to the previously found offset
f.write(bytearray([0xEB])) # patch the jump
f.close()
```

Comment: Shortly after posting the question, I managed to find the offset and to patch the program using python. This is EXACTLY how I did it. However, I realized the offset will change when the program updates, might need to make my solution a little more robust...

Comment: @NewReverser how does it change? what do you mean?

Comment: Between build versions the offset might change depending if they add features, change the code around, etc.

Comment: oh, I thought it changed in the same binary. in that case, you can use patterns to find your code. sadly I haven't ever done it with Olly, but in case you have IDA, it's easy as getting a sigmaker plugin (I can link one if you want), and then using it from your code. there's a lot of info about this on the internet, but do tell me if you need clarification on anything.

Comment: My mistake, it's not the build version. One is a 64 bit binary and the other is a 32 bit! If I were to create a patch for both binarys, I would need to find the offset for the 64 bit version... but olly only supports 32 bit? Would using IDA benefit me? I haven't really dug deep into IDA.

Comment: IDA is an amazing tool, more than what you seem to think. it also has a x64 version, so indeed you can use it to take signatures from both versions.

Comment: What we used to do in the old days is to look for some set of bytes rather than a specific offset...

Answer (score 2):

With OllyDBG2, there is an option for it : `Edit > Copy to Executable`

[image: Showing the context menu item described above]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a patch tool you dont need to code it. Use dUP (diablo2oo2 Universal Patcher) or R!SC Process Patcher to easily create a .exe that patches your defined offsets with your defined values.